# Does installation of packages persist in Live USB?

Tags: live-usb, customization, custom-installer

I burned a a LiveUSB of Ubuntu 17.04 using the startup disk creator.  I also allowed for 4 GB of space for the saving of files.  If I install Chrome, remove the drive, and put it in a different computer, will Google Chrome be available on subsequent boots?

Comment: It depends on whether or not the usb is created with persistence option. Normally Ubuntu is capable of doing so.

Comment: Since you've enabled 4GB space, I think you enabled it. But needs more information on how you created the usb. And I see the `customer-installer` tag. What was this for? Have you created some custom ubuntu remix?

Comment: I used the Ubuntu startup disk creator and allowed for 4GB in the section titled "When starting up from disk documents and settings will be (Checkmark) - Stored in reserved extra space"